# Show JavaScript result with html

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I have this JavaScript code which shows open and close ports. I want to show the result of this javaScript code on html page exactly as it is written in console.log.

```
<html>
<head>

 <script type="text/javascript">        
 var net = require('net'); 
 var ipStart = 0;
 var ipEnd = 245; 
 var timeout = 2000;

 while (ipStart <= ipEnd) {
 var count = ipStart;
    (function(count) {
    var hostOne = '192.168.0.' + count;
    var hostTwo = '192.168.1.' + count;
    var hostThree = '192.168.2.' + count;

    var socket = new net.Socket();
    socket.setTimeout(timeout, function() { socket.destroy(); });
    socket.connect(80, function() {

        console.log('IP Adress ' + hostOne + ' is on port 80 Open!');
        console.log('IP Adress ' + hostTwo + ' is on port 80 Open!');
        console.log('IP Adress ' + hostThree + ' is on port 80 Open!');
        });

        socket.on('error', function(e) {

        console.log('IP Adress ' + hostOne + ' is on port 80 Closed!');
        console.log('IP Adress ' + hostTwo + ' is on port 80 Closed!');
        console.log('IP Adress ' + hostThree + ' is on port 80 Closed!');
        });
    })(count);

    ipStart++;
 }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

This is a part of the result on terminal when I only run js file of it:

```
 IP Adress 192.168.0.244 is on port 80 Closed!
 IP Adress 192.168.1.244 is on port 80 Closed!
 IP Adress 192.168.2.244 is on port 80 Closed!
 IP Adress 192.168.0.245 is on port 80 Closed!
 IP Adress 192.168.1.245 is on port 80 Closed!
 IP Adress 192.168.2.245 is on port 80 Closed!
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Have you tried anything to accomplish this goal? Maybe replacing `console.log` with something to add text to the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
    <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="contents"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">        
     var net = require('net'); 
     var ipStart = 0;
     var ipEnd = 245; 
     var timeout = 2000;

     while (ipStart <= ipEnd) {
     var count = ipStart;
        (function(count) {
        var hostOne = '192.168.0.' + count;
        var hostTwo = '192.168.1.' + count;
        var hostThree = '192.168.2.' + count;
        var output ='';
        var socket = new net.Socket();
        socket.setTimeout(timeout, function() { socket.destroy(); });
        socket.connect(80, function() {

           output='IP Adress ' + hostOne + ' is on port 80 Open!';
           output=output + 'IP Adress ' + hostTwo + ' is on port 80 Open!';
           output=output + 'IP Adress ' + hostThree + ' is on port 80 Open!';
            });

            socket.on('error', function(e) {

            output=output + 'IP Adress ' + hostOne + ' is on port 80 Closed!';
            output=output + 'IP Adress ' + hostTwo + ' is on port 80 Closed!';
            output=output + 'IP Adress ' + hostThree + ' is on port 80 Closed!';
            });
        })(count);

        ipStart++;
     }
     getElementById('contents').innerHTML=output;

        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I have tried it. But unfortunately this does not show anything on the page for me.

Comment: This answer should work. But I do not really know what is the problem here. Because js file works properly. But in html file it does not show anything. But Thank you anyway

Comment: i updated the answer, it will work now, before the script was not getting the div id, now i declared the div before the script

Comment: tried on simple text, worked for me... try to debug js using firebug

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML +="IP Adress "+hostOne+" is on port 80 Closed!"
```

But if `window` object will not be loaded it'll throw error `Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined`. So you've to keep that in mind.